# How to change the values of multiple indexes?

Tags: python, arrays

```
worldArray = [["." for i in range(5)] for i in range(5)]
```

This produces a map that I can use for my game. It should look something like:

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Let's say the `'.'` represents a grass tile. If I wanted to replace a specific number of indexes to `'~'` instead to represent a water tile, what would be the easiest way of doing so? I want the map to look a bit like:

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['~', '~', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['~', '~', '~', '.', '.']]
```

I know I can manually go through and change each specific index to show the `'~'` tile, but the real in-game map I use is 40 x 40 instead -- which would make the job of individually replacing each index a bit tedious and redundant. I would like to be able to define which tiles I want replaced, i.e. row 4, columns 1 - 2; row 5, columns 1 - 3. how could I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a helper function

```
def replace_at_position(world_array, row_col_dict, repl_char):
    """
    Use row_col_dict in format of {row : (startOfRange, endOfRange)} to replace the characters
    inside the specific range at the specific row with repl_char
    """

    for row in row_col_dict.keys():
        startPos, endPos = row_col_dict[row]

        for i in range(startPos, endPos):
            worldArray[row][i] = repl_char
    return worldArray
```

You can use it like this:

```
worldArray = [["." for i in range(10)] for j in range(5)]

# replace row 2 (the third row) colums 0-4 (inclusive, exclusive, like range) with character '~'
worldArray = replace_at_position(worldArray, {2 : (0,10)}, '~')

#replace row 1 (the second row) colums 0-5 (inc, exc, like range) with character '~'
worldArray = replace_at_position(worldArray, {1 : (0, 5)}, '~')

pprint.pprint(worldArray)
```

This will result in:

```
[['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~', '~'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Slice notation is perfect for this:

```
from functools import partial

def tile(icon, row, col_start, col_end):
    worldArray[row][col_start:col_end] = icon * (col_end - col_start)

water = partial(tile, '~')
mountain = partial(tile, '^')

water(3, 0, 2)
water(4, 0, 3)
```

Comment: Ooops, I misread the question. Was thinking of random rows/columns (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I would define a function that returns whether or not to make it `~` instead of `.`.

```
"""
Determines if the game position is regular or not
"""
def isRegular(x,y):
    # Only replace Row 4 column 1 and 2 with ~
    return not (x==4 and y in [1,2])

worldArray = [["." if isRegular(x,y) else "~" for x in range(5) ] for y in range(5)]
```

You can change the `regular()` function to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I threw together a simple function you can run. Feel free to copy and paste it into the IDLE console:

```
>>> def a():
global worldArray
b = 1
while b < 2:
    c = (int(input('Row #: ')),int(input('Column-Leftbound: ')),int(input('Column-Rightbound: ')))
    worldArray[c[0]][c[1]] = '~'
    worldArray[c[0]][c[2]] = '~'
    d = c[2] - c[1]
    for i in range(d):
        worldArray[c[0]][c[1]+i] = '~'
    print(worldArray)
    b = int(input('b now equals: '))
>>> a() #This line is for you to call the function at the console
```

**Keep these things in mind:**

**Legitimate Row and Column numbers are from: 0-4.**

**Also, in order to exit the while loop I ask you to reset the value of b. You stay in the loop if you enter a value less than 2. Let me know if this helps. I tried to keep it very simple.**

.

.

As a side note,

worldArray = [["." for i in range(5)] for i in range(5)]

does not produce a nice and neat matrix for me.